# Listing travel experiences on a resume

Tags: resume, travel

Would it be acceptable - and perhaps beneficial - to list some of my cool travel experiences, say, to Istanbul, Norway, Moscow, on my resume?  I'm job searching now in New York and wonder whether that could communicate to hiring managers that I perhaps have an open mind and a somewhat broader perspective.  I was thinking of using one line on my resume to list some countries.

Comment: Do you mean business trips where you stayed at the locations for extended periods? Eg. 3+ months?

Answer (score 17):

In a word, no.

Employers aren't interested in travel unless it has to do with your work history. In fact, they're not interested in much of anything unless it pertains to your work history or **directly** how it will help you on the job.

Leave it off

Comment: Leave it off, for sure.

Comment: Exactly. If you worked internationally and have experience with doing business in other cultures, then absolutely list it. If the job involves living or working in a country where you spent significant time immersed in the culture, list it. Otherwise, no one is going to care if you were there for a week or two on vacation

Comment: @DLS3141 Exactly. If you're applying to Toyota USA it **might** be worthwhile to put that you have spent a lot of time in Japan and that sort of thing.

Answer (score 2):

## That's what the interview is for.

Make it interesting. Talk about your passions and your long terms plans and all the awesome stuff in your life then. The resume should **only** contain the bare minimum content to get you through to the interview. Show them the good stuff and nothing more.

**Caution**: I say this from experience, that if you're relying more on your resume and not your skill-set to get you through the interview process, then I'm afraid you have some real solid preparation to do.

Answer (score 2):

**No**

Unless the experience is directly relevent to the job in question of course!

As a hiring manager if I see someone's extensive travel history listed on their CV it would definitely put me off. *Especially* if it is regular and/or relatively recent as this positively *screams" that the candidate is just looking for a job to work at for a while so they can fund their next "adventure". In the case of travel that is further in the past then I tend to think they are either desperate to sound "interesting" or trying to "stand out", or worse - they are the sort of person that will never shut up about their "life changing" year backpacking round Asia when they were 19. Ugh!

Answer (score -4):

Yes.

It's not guaranteed to help, but it can. It cannot hurt either, so you might as well leave it in.

True story, years ago I travelled for about a year. My first job after that came about because the hiring manager loved Thailand, he'd been there on his honeymoon.

My interview with him was just an hour long discussion on diving and beaches. This was for a tech job, in banking, in San Fran, which is the last place you'd think would care.

The only reason we started on the topic was that, at the bottom of my CV, was a section "countries I've travelled to".

I would always leave in anything that makes the fact that you're interesting stand out.  I still keep in cool things like chernobyl or working on an elephant orphanage, and more normal spots like angkor wat, & machu picchu now.

Comment: This is not good advise.  Employers don't care that you have traveled.

Comment: Did you put it on your resume, or did this just come up naturally in conversation? I think that's a very important distinction.

Comment: @Mister they honestly do. they want well rounded people, who have a variety of life experiences. that helps in seeing problems from different angles. traveling itself shows innate curiosity, generally an ability to communicate, and motivation.

Comment: @whrrg yes, noted and added

Comment: The problem with one anecdote is that it doesn't say much about what happens most often / in general (because what happened may have been very uncommon) (assuming it can either help or hurt - if it couldn't hurt, then pointing out that it could help makes sense).

Comment: @dukeling id be amazed if anyone ever rejected a candidate "because they listed they they travelled in their cv", I imagine it's pretty harmless to do

Comment: It is very common to include a section for your personal interests.  If Travel is one of your personal interests, i don't see any problem with including it in your CV.

Comment: @bharal However candidates have been rejected because there's too much stuff on their CV, if your CV is over 2 pages, that normally heads straight for the bin. If you can fit it on, with everything else within 2 pages, why not. But most CVs will take 2 pages just getting the important stuff on, not sure there'd be room for travel destinations.

Comment: @bharal Yes, if it comes up in conversation you could mention travel in an interview. However, the question was specifically about putting this info in the CV/resume.

Comment: This could be highly subjective to your company, because AFAIK it's rare. Nevertheless, I liked the way you presented it without clutter, with just one line : "Countries I've traveled to"

Comment: @bharal It's not about singular red flags that will get you outright rejected, it's about something that could count against you and add up to a rejection, which generally doesn't take much at the screening stage. It could count against you if it's considered irrelevant to your job (as judged by the potential employer), because then you'd be wasting valuable space on your resume and taking focus away from more relevant things.